# How to display User Points Top 5 Contributors with the users profile image?

Tags: users, userpoints, media

I'm trying to display the user's profile image/avatar next to the [userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) top 5 contributors block. The profile image is a field created from Profiles 2 module - `field_profile_image`.